# I want to add id to div same as first value of an observable array in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I want to add the id according to first color name. But it is not added as i want and it gives the javascript error:
**Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: undefined is not a function;
Bindings value: attr: {id: $root.colors()[0].color}** 
The code sample i have tried. 
Html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <li><span data-bind="text:color"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="attr: {id: $root.colors()[0].color}">
    Make this div id associated with first color name of colors array.
</div>
```

Knockout:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.self = this;
    self.colors = ko.observableArray([{
        color: 'red'},
    {
        color: 'blue'},
    {
        color: 'yellow'}]);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your view model - you create `self` property on your object `this.self = this` but then you use it like it is a local variable. Try to change it to be local variable:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.colors = ko.observableArray([{
        color: 'red'},
    {
        color: 'blue'},
    {
        color: 'yellow'}]);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```